# Pagination error when upgrade from cakephp 1.3 to 2.0

Tags: php, cakephp, upgrade

I am upgrading cakephp 1.3 to 2.0

I am getting below error in error log

```
Error: [MissingTableException] Table aros_acos for model Permission was not found in   datasource default.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'table' => 'aros_acos',
  'class' => 'Permission',
  'ds' => 'default',
)
Request URL: /users/show?%2Fusers%2Fshow=

Stack Trace:
#0 /lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(3498): Model->setSource('aros_acos')
#1 /lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(1063): Model->getDataSource()
#2 /lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(2902): DboSource->read(Object(User), Array)
#3 /lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(2874): Model->_readDataSource('count', Array)
#4 /app/Controller/Component/PaginationComponent.php(212): Model->find('count', 'status!='DL'')
#5 /app/Controller/UsersController.php(108): PaginationComponent->init('status!='DL'')
#6 [internal function]: UsersController->show()
#7 /lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php(490):   ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(UsersController), Array)
#8 /lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(185): Controller->invokeAction(Object(CakeRequest))
#9 /lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(160): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(UsersController), Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#10 /app/webroot/index.php(108): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
```

UsersController.php error section

```
$criteria = "status!='1'";
$this->Pagination->direction = 'ASC';
$this->Pagination->sortBy = 'username';
//********
$this->Pagination->setPageLimit($page_limit);
list($order, $limit, $page) = $this->Pagination->init($criteria); // Added
```

PaginationComponent.php

```
 $count = $this->controller->{$this->modelClass}->find('count', $criteria);
```

Please let me know what is going wrong.

Thanks,

Comment: There is many differences between branch 1.3 and 2.x. Firstly read: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html

Comment: The error has nothing to do with your Pagination. It is a DB error based on a invalid database setup - and will most likely occur on every page that is not publically accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you even tried to read and understand the error message? Debugging starts by reading (and understanding) error messages if you get some.

**[MissingTableException] Table aros_acos for model Permission was not found in datasource default.**

That means that the table aros_acos doesn't exist in your database.

Comment: Table aros_acos and the model already there. But still getting error. That is the only reason I posted it here.

Comment: Well, read it to the end... You permission model is trying to use that table for whatever reason and can't find it. Your job to figure out why.